# Разбор подходов в программировании

Tags: javascript

В интернете нашел 2 подхода в программировании, помогите разобраться, как они по грамотному называются, и в каком случае какой лучше использовать.

Ссылки на грамотные мануалы приветствуются :)

Подход №1:

```
var myVar = function() {
    return {
        myFunc: function() {
            ...
        }
    };
}();
myVar.myFunc()
```

Подход №2:

```
function myClass(){
    this.myProperty = 1;
    this.myFunction = function(){
        ...
    }
};
myVar = new myClass();
myVar.myProperty = 1;
myVar.myFunction();
```

Comment: как бы есть еще один, который использует прототипы

Comment: @Umer, второй это как раз частный случай

Comment: @Grundy, в смысле частный случай прототипного подхода?

Comment: @Umer, ну да, частный случай прототипного подхода

Comment: @Alexander, а там где вы их нашли не было описания?

Comment: @Grundy нет, это были просто уже готовые куски кода.

Comment: Ответ потянет на пару часов работы ) посмотрите http://it-ebooks.info/book/724/ там ссылка на скачку есть. Или в крации https://scotch.io/bar-talk/4-javascript-design-patterns-you-should-know

Comment: первый - функциональный, второй - ооп. олсо "в крации" это что аще значит?

Answer (score 1):

Это не подход в программировании. Это 2 вида создания объектов в JS, из 4 минимум.

https://habrahabr.ru/company/nixsolutions/blog/302518/
http://largescalejs.ru/
https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-object-creation-patterns-best-practises/